# How to overwrite the laravel DatabaseManager method

Tags: laravel, overwrite

There is a method in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php

```
/**
 * Parse the connection into an array of the name and read / write type.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return array
 */
protected function parseConnectionName($name)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultConnection();

    return Str::endsWith($name, ['::read', '::write'])
                        ? explode('::', $name, 2) : [$name, null];
}
```

If I want to overwrite this method how would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since this method is protected, you have to create a class that extends `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` in your `app` folder and override that function with your own

Then inject your custom class into the container by binding a singleton

```php
$this->app->bind('Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager', function () {
    return new App\CustomClass;
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: where would you put that code? in some custom provider or just in AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: Either, just a service provider

Comment: hm I created the class, extended the DatabaseManager and put that code in AppServiceProvider.php but it doesn't use my class... what could be wrong

Comment: Same problem here. The proposed solution does not work. Binding a custom sub-class of `DatabaseManager` is not possible this way.